# how to use the app function in android

Tags: android

I tried to add the xmlns:app but it became brown and some code become wrong due to that.

Please see the picture below and tell me what I should do to fix it.
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: see my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

Use `app:showAsAction="never"` instead

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Appcomapct library so you need to make change as bellow:

Try this

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

change with this

```
app:showAsAction="never"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line:

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

to:

```
app:showAsAction="never"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a support library for older android versions , then the showAsAction attribute is not available for android.Instead, it is provided by the support library for which you'll have to define the namespace.

```
android:showAsAction:"never
```

to

```
app:showAsAction:"never"
```